# monit: failed to restart

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, monit

I am using monit for sidekiq

while I am running the monit log file, it is showing the error.

```
[EDT Jun 18 09:50:11] error    : 'sidekiq_site' process is not running
[EDT Jun 18 09:50:11] info     : 'sidekiq_site' trying to restart
[EDT Jun 18 09:50:11] info     : 'sidekiq_site' start: /bin/bash
[EDT Jun 18 09:51:41] error    : 'sidekiq_site' failed to start
```

**/etc/monit/conf.d/sidekiq.conf**

```
check process sidekiq_site
  with pidfile /var/www/project/shared/pids/sidekiq.pid
  start program = "bash -c 'cd /var/www/project/current ; RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec sidekiq --index 0 --pidfile /var/www/project/shared/pids/sidekiq.pid --environment production --logfile /var/www/project/shared/log/sidekiq.log --daemon'" as uid root and gid root with timeout 90 seconds
  stop program = "bash -c 'if [ -d /var/www/project/current ] && [ -f /var/www/project/shared/pids/sidekiq.pid ] && kill -0 `cat /var/www/project/shared/pids/sidekiq.pid`> /dev/null 2>&1; then cd /var/www/project/current && bundle exec sidekiqctl stop /var/www/project/shared/pids/sidekiq.pid 1 ; else echo 'Sidekiq is not running'; fi'" as uid root and gid root
  if totalmem is greater than 200 MB for 2 cycles then restart # eating up memory?
  group site_sidekiq
```

**/etc/monit/monitrc**

```
set daemon 30

set logfile /var/log/monit.log
set idfile /var/lib/monit/id
set statefile /var/lib/monit/state

set eventqueue
    basedir /var/lib/monit/events
    slots 100



set httpd port 2812
   allow admin:""
set httpd port 2812 and
    use address xx.xxx.xx.xx
    allow xx.xx.xx.xx

check system trrm_server
  if loadavg(5min) > 2 for 2 cycles then alert
  if memory > 75% for 2 cycles then alert
  if cpu(user) > 75% for 2 cycles then alert

include /etc/monit/conf.d/*
```

Comment: Try changing one of the ports `set httpd port 2812` to something else.

Comment: Have you tried to launch side_kiq manually?

Comment: @zmii : trying manually it is working. But while using moint is not working.

Comment: Starting monit daemon with http interface at [xx.xxx.xx.xx:2815]
[EDT Jun 18 10:05:55] info     : Starting monit HTTP server at [xx.xx.xx.xx:2815]
[EDT Jun 18 10:05:55] info     : monit HTTP server started
[EDT Jun 18 10:05:55] info     : 'trrm_server' Monit started
[EDT Jun 18 10:05:55] error    : 'sidekiq_site' process is not running
[EDT Jun 18 10:05:55] info     : 'sidekiq_site' trying to restart
[EDT Jun 18 10:05:55] info     : 'sidekiq_site' start: /bin/bash

Comment: Check my question and my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51825517/7266232) for this issue.
hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

When running a start/stop event in monit there is no path variable set, therefore all programs must have absolute paths, even your call to bash.

> No environment variables are used by Monit